# Ordenar labels e inputs en una navbar

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, navbar

Mi problema es que no puedo ordenar 2 `label` con 2 `input` en la barra de navegación (como la de un inicio de sesión parecida a la de Facebook). Suelo hacerlo con `placeholder` pero intentándolo de esta manera los `label` quedan a la izquierda de los `input` en vez de arriba. Usé el sistema `grid` de Bootstrap creando 2 filas con 2 columnas cada una. En la de arriba los `label` y en la de abajo los `input`. ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

```html
<nav className="navbar navbar-dark " style={styles}>
    <div className="container">
      <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <form className="form-inline">
          <div className="form-row">
              <div className="col-sm-6">
                  <label>correo</label>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-6">
                  <label>contraseña</label>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-row">
              <div className="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" className="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="correo electronico" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"/>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" className="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="contraseña" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"/>
              </div>
          </div>
      </form>
  </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente no sé si estás usando algún framework, ya que `className` no es un atributo de HTML.

Lo que intentas hacer usando `form-row` y `columns` es muy rebuscado. Te sugiero mantener las cosas lo más simple posible. Además estás usando una clase de Bootstrap llamada `form-inline` que como su nombre indica pondrá todos los elementos en la misma linea.

**PROBLEMA**

Tu deseas hacer una barra de navegación que tenga un `input` para el correo y otro `input` para el password. Deseas que cada input tenga un `label` justo encima. Lo quieres parecido a la forma en que se ve la página de Facebook, pero vas a usar Bootstrap. (Facebook no usa Bootstrap para su barra nav, por lo tanto no se verá exactamente igual).

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para lograr lo que te propones vamos a usar las siguientes clases de Bootstrap:

1. [`navbar`, `navbar-brand`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)
2. [`form-group`, `form-control`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/)
3. [`row`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Lo que haremos es crear un elemento `nav` y le daremos el estilo con las clases `navbar`, `navbar-dark` y `bg-dark` de Bootstrap.

Dentro de nuestro elemento `nav`, pondremos un elemento 'anchor' con la clase `navbar-brand`.

También pondremos un `div` con la clase `row` y haremos que los elementos hijos se alineen a la derecha con la clase `justify-content-right`

Dentro del `div` pondremos dos elementos `form`, los cuales usarán la clase `form-group`. Cada uno de estos elementos contendrá un `label` y un `input`. Además a cada elemento `form` le asignaremos la clase `mx-2` que nos dará un margen de '2 rem' por derecha e izquierda, de esta forma los elementos no se verán tan ajustados.

Por último, a cada elemento `label` le asignaremos la clase `text-light` para poder contrastar con nuestro fondo, porque de lo contrario las letras no serán visibles.

Una forma en que puedes usar estos elementos es la siguiente:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="row justify-content-right">
    <form class="form-group mx-2">
      <label class="text-light" for="correo">Correo:</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="correo" name="correo">
    </form>
    <form class="form-group mx-2">
      <label class="text-light" for="password">Password:</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="password" name="password">
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Como puedes ver en el resultado, ya tienes los elementos `label` sobre el correspondiente `input`.

La idea es que analices bien el código, no solo es copiar y pegar. Revisa bien la documentación de Bootstrap. Es un framework que realmente nos hace la vida más fácil, pero sólo si le prestamos atención a los detalles.

Comment: si estoy usando react. vaya muchas gracias por tu ayuda me sirvió muchísimo.

Comment: Me alegra poder ayudarte. Si la respuesta es satisfactoria la puedes dar como válida, asi tu reputación y la mía suben. ;)

Comment: cool ya lo hare, lo siento por tardar no sabia que se podía soy nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

Hace lo siguiente, mete 1 input y 1 label dentro de un div padre.

Label
       Input
<\div>

En CSS
Padre{
   Display : flex;
   Flex-direction: column
}

Comment: Hola, por favor leer [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Se agradece mucho tu intención, pero la idea del sitio es dar ejemplos claros y demostrables, para eso puedes usar las herramientas que dispones en el sitio.